# Getting a substring results an error

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following line :

```
if ( dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Length >= 13 ){      
                e.Graphics.DrawString
(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Substring(0,14),
print6B, Brushes.Black, x-10, 130 + height);
                }
                else {
```

Because of the Substring method i get this error: 
index and length must refer to a location within the string c#

What is the best method to get the first 14 characters of the string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine to me. Are you sure you aren't grabbing the header row? It's a common error when dealing with the gridview.

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Length > 13)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Substring(0,14), print6B, Brushes.Black, x-10, 130 + height);
    }
}
```

You can see more on the row types [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx)

Comment: i have this above: for (int i = 1; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

Comment: You sure it's not grabbing the footer either (assuming there is one)?

Answer (score 3):

That will work fine if there *are* 14 characters, but it won't if there are fewer than 14 characters. You could write your own extension method:

```
public string SafeSubstring(this string text, int index, int count)
{
    // TODO: null checking
    return text.Length > index + count ? text.Substring(index, count)
                                       : text.Substring(index);
}
```

Note that this will only help you avoid exceptions due to the count - you'll still need to make sure that `index` is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Check the length of the string first - if it's less than 14 characters return the whole string, otherwise SubString(0,14).

Answer (score 0):

```
string strToWrite = string.Empty;
if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.Length > 14){
   strToWrite = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Substring(0,14);
else 
   strToWrite = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
e.Graphics.DrawString(strToWrite, print6B, Brushes.Black, x-10, 130 + height);
```